# Node.JS code fails without error on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, curl, error-handling, firebase

I have the simplest code for firebase :

```
var Firebase=require('firebase');
var Ref=new Firebase('http://mydb.firebaseio.com/requests');
Ref.push({name:"checkin",type:"mandatory"},function(response){
console.log(response);
});
```

and I'm running it with SSH in command line on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. For some reason the push method runs but doesn't push anything and doesn't even show an error. I tried logging the error to a file but the file remains empty. I also tried catching an uncaught exception from the process, no luck. There basically isn't an error to show. How should I catch an error so I can investigate further ?

Extra information :

-Node.JS version installed on the server is 12.4 .

-One thing I noticed is there  is no certificate file on the server and for example I can't use curl with an https url or PPA to download a package.

-Ubuntu 12.04.

-When I push to firebase using a PHP script it works fine but nodeJS fails to do it.

-The server is in a hospital's internal network and connects to internet through a proxy. Certain HTTPS websites are allowed on port 80 , the rest are blocked . Some similar policies might be in place for other ports and protocols.

Comment: If it were me, I'd open a browser on the server and see if I could view the site "http://mydb.firebaseio.com".  You might be surprised; your I.T. people could be blocking simple port 80 traffic like this.  It's possible that the proxy could be fouling things up.  You say "Certain HTTPS websites are allowed on port 80..." but this doesn't make sense to me since HTTP = 80 and HTTPS is usually port 443.

Comment: When I use google with https it works but it's very slow (!) but if I remove the s from the end it works very fast, on the other hand when I try to cURL from dropbox it opens a warning page that the hospital IT guys just made. My question is why does my PHP script has no problem contacting firebase but NodeJS does ?